# Linq to SQL with Multiple Aggregates, Sum and Max

Tags: vb.net, linq

Note Updated:
Thanks all for any and all help, for those that are vb.net savvy here is the self contained example ...

```
Structure Stuff
        public client as String
        public BDate as DateTime
        public KB as long
        public sub new(client as string, BDate as DateTime, KB as Long)
            Me.client = client
            Me.BDate = BDate
            Me.KB = KB
        end sub
    End Structure
Sub Main

Dim Stuffs as new List(Of Stuff)
Stuffs.Add(new Stuff("dev0db05", "6/25/2012  7:00:35 AM",1))
Stuffs.Add(new Stuff("dev0db05", "6/25/2012  7:00:35 AM",1))
Stuffs.Add(new Stuff("dev0db05", "6/25/2012  7:00:35 AM",1))
Stuffs.Add(new Stuff("dev0db05", "6/26/2012  7:00:35 AM",2))
Stuffs.Add(new Stuff("dev0db05", "6/26/2012  7:00:35 AM",2))
Stuffs.Add(new Stuff("dev0db05", "6/26/2012  7:00:35 AM",2))
Stuffs.Add(new Stuff("dev0db05", "6/27/2012  7:00:35 AM",3))
Stuffs.Add(new Stuff("dev0db05", "6/27/2012  7:00:35 AM",3))
Stuffs.Add(new Stuff("dev0db05", "6/27/2012  7:00:35 AM",3))
Stuffs.Add(new Stuff("dev0db05", "6/28/2012  7:00:35 AM",4))
Stuffs.Add(new Stuff("dev0db05", "6/28/2012  7:00:35 AM",4))
Stuffs.Add(new Stuff("dev0db05", "6/28/2012  7:00:35 AM",4))

dim q = From c In Stuffs _
  where c.client= "dev0db05" _
  order by c.BDate _
  group c by c.Client,c.bdate into g = group _
  select ClientName = Client, BDate = DateTime.Parse(bdate).ToShortDateString, SumKB = g.sum(Function(p) p.kb)

Output:
ClientName BDate SumKB 
dev0db05 6/25/2012 3 
dev0db05 6/26/2012 6 
dev0db05 6/27/2012 9 
dev0db05 6/28/2012 12
```

So in this example i would like to only have the highest SumKB returned (12) for dev0db05
I understand i have to do a MAX but don't know how against the above ...
Thanks, probably too simple but i'm at a loss ...

For the following Linq Query, how do I return only the highest value, i.e 259835919?
Thanks! I'm a newbie and trying to understand.

```
dim q = From c In Stuff _
where c.client= "dev0db05" _
where c.policy = "mcg-oracle-db" _
order by c.BackupDate _
group c by key = 0, c.Client,c.backupdate into g = group _
select ClientName = Client, BDate = DateTime.Parse(backupdate).ToShortDateString, SumKB = g.sum(Function(p) p.kilobytes)
```

returns:

```
dev0db05    5/20/2012   163160396
dev0db05    5/27/2012   235918153
dev0db05    6/3/2012    259813647
dev0db05    6/10/2012   259835151
dev0db05    6/13/2012   23824838
dev0db05    6/14/2012   259578160
dev0db05    6/15/2012   23864427
dev0db05    6/16/2012   259578127
**dev0db05  6/17/2012   259835919**
dev0db05    6/18/2012   23858283
dev0db05    6/19/2012   259575055
dev0db05    6/20/2012   33412
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, unfortuanatly I get:

Comment: Range variable name can be inferred only from a simple or qualified name with no arguments.

Comment: Would you post your original code? this code has too many compile errors (e.g `c.client= "dev0db05"` wont work and should be like `c.client== "dev0db05"`).

Comment: Actually it is correct it's in vb, i will try and convert, this is the original code

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: It appears to be VB code, not C#.

Comment: Yes I see, sorry I'm not good in vb, I thought it's a code in notepad++ or something without test.

Answer (score 0):

Alright the following is the solution. Is this the most efficient way to do it?

```
Structure Stuff
  public client as String
  public BackupDate as DateTime
  public Kilobytes as double
  public sub new(client as string, BackupDate as DateTime, Kilobytes as double)
  Me.client = client
  Me.BackupDate = BackupDate
  Me.Kilobytes = Kilobytes
  end sub
End Structure

Sub Main
Dim Stuffs as new list(Of Stuff)
Stuffs.Add(new Stuff("dev0db05", "6/25/2012  7:00:35 AM",1))
Stuffs.Add(new Stuff("dev0db05", "6/25/2012  7:00:35 AM",1))
Stuffs.Add(new Stuff("dev0db05", "6/25/2012  7:00:35 AM",1))
Stuffs.Add(new Stuff("dev0db05", "6/26/2012  7:00:35 AM",2))
Stuffs.Add(new Stuff("dev0db05", "6/26/2012  7:00:35 AM",2))
Stuffs.Add(new Stuff("dev0db05", "6/26/2012  7:00:35 AM",2))
Stuffs.Add(new Stuff("dev0db06", "6/27/2012  7:00:35 AM",3))
Stuffs.Add(new Stuff("dev0db06", "6/27/2012  7:00:35 AM",3))
Stuffs.Add(new Stuff("dev0db06", "6/27/2012  7:00:35 AM",3))
Stuffs.Add(new Stuff("dev0db06", "6/28/2012  7:00:35 AM",4))
Stuffs.Add(new Stuff("dev0db06", "6/28/2012  7:00:35 AM",4))
Stuffs.Add(new Stuff("dev0db06", "6/28/2012  7:00:35 AM",4))
Stuffs.Add(new Stuff("dev0db09", "6/27/2012  7:00:35 AM",5))
Stuffs.Add(new Stuff("dev0db09", "6/27/2012  7:00:35 AM",5))
Stuffs.Add(new Stuff("dev0db09", "6/27/2012  7:00:35 AM",5))
Stuffs.Add(new Stuff("dev0db03", "6/28/2012  7:00:35 AM",6))
Stuffs.Add(new Stuff("dev0db03", "6/28/2012  7:00:35 AM",6))
Stuffs.Add(new Stuff("dev0db03", "6/28/2012  7:00:35 AM",6))

dim jj = From t1 In ((From t0 In Stuffs _
  Group t0 By t0.Client,t0.BackupDate Into g = Group  _
  Select SumKB = CType(g.Sum(Function(p) p.Kilobytes),long?),Client,BDate = CStr(CDate(BackupDate)))) _
where t1.client = "dev0db05" _
Group t1 By t1.Client Into g = Group  _
Select Client, MaxKB = CType(g.Max(Function(p) p.SumKB),long?)
```

Returns 6 for dev0db05